# excel: run time error 1004 in advanced filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sheet where I applied a series of subs to get what I want. The last one is an Advanced Filter.

You can see how my main sheet is below:

[image]

My criteria is **C31:K32** and the results should be pasted from line 38. It gets the information from that sheet called **AUX**:

[image]
The complete code is below:

```
Sub FiltroAloc()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim res

Set ws1 = Sheets("CONSULTA")
Set ws2 = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL_ATUAL")
Set ws3 = Sheets("AUX")



    For i = 1 To 100
        For j = 1 To 11
            If ((ws1.Cells(29, 5).Value < ws2.Cells(i, 7).Value) And (ws1.Cells(29, 6).Value > ws2.Cells(i, 7).Value)) Or ((ws1.Cells(29, 5).Value < ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value) And (ws1.Cells(29, 6).Value > ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value)) Then
                ws3.Cells(i, j) = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
            ElseIf (ws1.Cells(29, 5) = "") And (ws1.Cells(29, 6) = "") Then
                ws3.Cells(i, j) = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Call Esvaziar

End Sub

Sub Esvaziar()

Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("AUX")
Set r = ws.Range("A1:K450")

rows = r.rows.Count

    For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then
        r.rows(i).Delete

        End If
    Next

    Call AutoFilter

End Sub
```

All my code works fine! After that, I started to record my Advanced Filter as a Macro with AutoFilter name.

When I finished to record it worked fine and load all information, because I recorded it with nothing in my criteria.

The problem is when I assing to my "Filtrar" button. It gave me

> Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

And that is the code:

```
Sub AutoFilter()
'
' AutoFilter Macro
'

'
    Sheets("AUX").Range("A1:K176").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:="CONSULTA!Criteria", CopyToRange:=Range("CONSULTA!Extract") _
        , Unique:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
    Range("G3").Select
End Sub
```

And the highlighted part:

```
Sheets("AUX").Range("A1:K176").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:="CONSULTA!Criteria", CopyToRange:=Range("CONSULTA!Extract") _
        , Unique:=False
```

I tried a lot of things but I guess I'm missing something. I don't know where to find my range problem... Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try it with `CriteriaRange:=worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("Criteria")` and `CopyToRange:=worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("Extract")`.

Comment: You might want to stay away from naming your subroutines with VBA command names...

Comment: I didn't realize... I guess I'll change that name.

Comment: @Jeeped sorry for taking a long time to verify this, but now it's working! Thank you. Before I didn't need to define criteria in Advanced Filter that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with `CriteriaRange:=worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("Criteria")` and `CopyToRange:=worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("Extract")`

```
Sheets("AUX").Range("A1:K176").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("Criteria"), _
    CopyToRange:=worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("Extract"), Unique:=False
```